# don't want to edit the data in the kendoUI editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I am using kendoui editor.I am loading the data in the editor.I want to make this readable only.make it as non editable.how can i make the data inside the editor as non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an editor to show read only data?

Why not create a separate  underneath the KendoUI Editor and use that for read-only information.

Then you can toggle the visibility between the editor and div as needed.